# Reading and validating REG_BINARY where REG_QWORD is expected

Tags: delphi, registry, delphi-10.4-sydney

According to [Block untrusted fonts in an enterprise](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/block-untrusted-fonts-in-enterprise) the `MitigationOptions` key should be a `REG_QWORD` filled with (hex) values 1000000000000, 2000000000000 or 3000000000000.

However, the `MitigationOptions` key in my registry is a `REG_BINARY`.
I created a test `REG_QWORD` value `QWordTest` according to that documentation, then read both with the code below (32 bit).

[image]

This outputs:

```
Key opened
QWordTest value exists
Data type:  rdUnknown
Data size:  8
Bytes read:    0 0 0 0 0 0 2 0

MitigationOptions value exists
Data type:  rdBinary
Data size:  24
Bytes read:    0 0 0 0 0 0 2 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0

*** Untrusted fonts blocked: False
```

Obviously, Delphi does not know about `REG_QWORD`:
`TRegDataType = (rdUnknown, rdString, rdExpandString, rdInteger, rdBinary);`

Question:

I need to know if untrusted fonts are blocked (1000000000000).
Given that I may either encounter a `REG_QWORD` or a `REG_BINARY`, would just testing for `lByteArray[6] = 1` be sufficient and reliable?

Code:

```
procedure TFrmReadRegBinary.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
   lDataType  : TRegdataType;
   lByteArray : TBytes;
   l,lDataSize: Integer;
   lOutput    : string;
begin
   Memo1.Lines.Clear;
   with TRegistry.Create(KEY_READ) do
   begin
      try
         try
            RootKey := HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE;
            if (OpenKey('SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Kernel\', false)) then
            begin
               Memo1.Lines.Add('Key opened');
               if ValueExists('QWordTest') then  // REG_QWORD
               begin
                  Memo1.Lines.Add('QWordTest value exists');
                  lDataType := GetDataType('QWordTest');
                  Memo1.Lines.Add('Data type:  '+ GetEnumName(TypeInfo(TRegdataType),Ord(lDataType)));
                  lDataSize := GetDataSize('QWordTest');
                  Memo1.Lines.Add('Data size:  '+ IntToStr(lDataSize));
                  SetLength(lByteArray,lDataSize);
                  ReadBinaryData('QWordTest', lByteArray[0], lDataSize);
                  lOutput := '  ';
                  for l := 0 to lDataSize - 1 do
                     lOutput := lOutput + ' ' + IntToStr(lByteArray[l]);
                  Memo1.Lines.Add('Bytes read: ' + lOutput);
               end
               else
                  Memo1.Lines.Add('QWordTest value does not exist');
               Memo1.Lines.Add('');
               if ValueExists('MitigationOptions') then  // REG_BINARY or REG_QWORD
               begin
                  Memo1.Lines.Add('MitigationOptions value exists');
                  lDataType := GetDataType('MitigationOptions');
                  Memo1.Lines.Add('Data type:  '+ GetEnumName(TypeInfo(TRegdataType),Ord(lDataType)));
                  lDataSize := GetDataSize('MitigationOptions');
                  Memo1.Lines.Add('Data size:  '+ IntToStr(lDataSize));
                  SetLength(lByteArray,lDataSize);
                  ReadBinaryData('MitigationOptions', lByteArray[0], lDataSize);
                  lOutput := '  ';
                  for l := 0 to lDataSize - 1 do
                     lOutput := lOutput + ' ' + IntToStr(lByteArray[l]);
                  Memo1.Lines.Add('Bytes read: ' + lOutput);
                  Memo1.Lines.Add('');
                  Memo1.Lines.Add('*** Untrusted fonts blocked: '+ BoolToStr(lByteArray[6] = 1,true));
               end
               else
                  Memo1.Lines.Add('MitigationOptions value does not exist');
            end
            else
               Memo1.Lines.Add('Key not opened (not found)');
         except
            on E:Exception do Memo1.Lines.Add('ERROR: ' + E.Message);
         end;
      finally
         Free;
      end;
   end;
end;
```

Comment: Just use [`RegQueryValueEx()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winreg/nf-winreg-regqueryvalueexa) directly, which supports all data types for decades already and can treat anything in binary.

Comment: @AmigoJack Good suggestion, that tells me more reliably if it's a REG_QWORD(_LITTLE_ENDIAN), rather than relying on 'unknown' and 8 bytes. Given that our system group policy inserted a REG_BINARY instead of the expected (documented) REG_QWORD still leaves me with the question whether `lByteArray[6] = 1` is a reliable test IN BOTH CASES (I don't have a system available where MitigationOptions *is* a REG_QWORD)

Comment: The REG_BINARY data type might have been created wrongly already because of "simulating" a QWORD. Also [those are surely flags](https://theryuu.github.io/ifeo-mitigationoptions.txt), so you're better off testing against `(byte & $F) = 1` or even only `(byte & $8) = 1`.